# Django - How to return all objects in a QuerySet in their subclass form, rather than their parent class form?

Tags: python, django, model, polymorphism

I have a class `Set` with a many-to-many relationship to `Item`. I have lots of 'set' objects all containing lots of 'items'.

However, the `Item` class has been subclassed to create `Article`, `Podcast`, `Video`, and `Episode`. Basically, everything on the database was originally an Item. If `my_set` is a `Set` instance, containing `Items` - how do I create a Queryset which returns those objects in their subclass form? Ie, rather than me getting a Queryset full of Item instances, I get a Queryset with `Article`, `Episode`, `Video`, `Podcast` instances.

How would I get `my_set.objects.all().as_subclass()' to work?

```
class Item(models.Model, AdminVideoMixin):
   base_attributes = 'foo'

     def as_episode(self):
       return Episode.objects.get(slug=self.slug)

class Video(Item): 
   class specific fields

class Article(Item):
   class specific fields

class Podcast(Item):
   class specific fields

class Episode(Item):
   class specific fields

class Set(Item):
    front_page = models.BooleanField(max_length=300, blank=False, default=False, null=False)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, related_name='in_sets', through='SetMeta', max_length=5000,)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('foo')

    def ordered(self):
        return self.items.all().order_by('-itemOrder__order')

    def episodes(self):
        episode_list = []
        for each_item in self.items.all():
           episode_list.append(each_item.as_episode())
        return episode_list


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

As you can see I tried two methods - to write a model method on Item() which returns itself as an Episode - but this only worked for single instances rather than a Queryset. As such I wrote a method on Set which can perform that method on all items within the self, but this doesn't produce a Queryset, just a list, and it feels messy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: have just skimmed the [django-polymorphic documentation](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#making-your-models-polymorphic) again, and it seems to be *exactly* what you want. So the rest of my answer is probably not very useful, unless you are prohibited from taking code out of [django-packages](https://djangopackages.org/packages/p/django-polymorphic/)

I don't think Django provides a way to express a queryset that returns objects of more than one model type. Querysets are supposed to map inro SQL queries, and I don't think SQL can return rows from more than one table mixed up. (I'm not an SQL expert, so I may be wrong). However, if you don't want a list, Python provides a means to take a queryset and apply a transformation to each `Item` instance it returns: a generator function.   So, for example, you could code

```
 def items_as_subclasses(qs):
     for instance in qs:
         try:
             yield instance.video
             continue
         except Video.DoesNotExist:
             pass
         try:
             yield instance.article
             continue
         except Article.DoesNotExist:
              pass

         try: ...

         raise ProbableCodingError(
            f"Item instance id={instance.id} does not have a known subclass"
         )
```

and then write

```
for item_subclass_instance in items_as_subclasses(queryset):
    # whatever
```

or indeed pass `"items":items_as_subclasses( queryset)` into a template rendering 
context.

If there is a long list of possible subclasses it might be better to have a `subclass_type` field in the base class, and use that to go straight to the only valid subclass field.

There's a nullable OneToOne link from the base class to its particular subclass, so you can write querysets that interrogate subclasses.

Or you could investigate [django-polymorphic](https://djangopackages.org/packages/p/django-polymorphic/), which I once skimmed, and which I vaguely remember is for this sort of usage.